# Is there a new TIE fighter model in the Solo Movie?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

I was recently watching the [Solo trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNW0B0HsvVs) and I noticed that there is a TIE fighter with an attachment (possibly extra blasters?) on the left-hand side of the pilot's cockpit:

[image: A new fighter with attachment?]

Is this a new TIE fighter, or one that has been brought in from legends?

Comment: I cannot find any article on [Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE_Series#Notes_and_references) that explains what this model is.

Comment: Maybe the TIE pilot added "special modifications" like Han did for the Millenium Falcon?

Comment: First thing I noticed was not the attachment you reference, but the shape.  The solar panels are much smaller in relation to the cockpit than a standard Tie Fighter.  It definitely looks like a different model.  The ones in the background appear to be the more conventional Tie Fighter

Comment: Possibly testing a variant with a rear gunner position? Would make sense, given a common dogfighting tactic on screen seems to be to get behind the enemy.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/7vf690/a_closer_look_at_the_new_tie_fighter_from_the/

Comment: The extra pod looks too small for another person.  I'd guess the pod contains sensors, based on the clouds they're flying through.

Comment: This is confidential Imperial information, how dare you Rebel spies try to get our secrets! Rebel scum!

Comment: Since Solo is a prequel that takes place prior to episode IV, that would be an old TIE fighter, not a new one.

Comment: here it is in action: https://youtu.be/K9PkToULL1c?t=1m6s

Comment: Technically, wouldn't it be an "OLD" TIE Fighter? Now we need some explanation as to why they stopped using it. Unless they make MORE changes to the Original Trilogy to add it in...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Yes](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2404402/lucasfilm-reveals-information-about-new-tie-fighter-in-solo-a-star-wars-story)**

> Compensating for the relative fragility of the unshielded TIE starfighter is the armored TIE/rb, a reinforced heavy starfighter with much more powerful laser cannons.
>
> <sub><sup>[Lucasfilm Reveals Information About New Tie Fighter In Solo: A Star Wars Story](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2404402/lucasfilm-reveals-information-about-new-tie-fighter-in-solo-a-star-wars-story)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 3):

There's some additional information to be found in the film's [Official Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story_The_Official_Guide). The 'TIE/rb heavy starfighter' is an upgraded version of the 'TIE/ln fighter', incorporating heavier armour and more firepower than is usually found on a line model fighter. The ship also includes an onboard droid intelligence and enhanced solar collectors.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would guess it's some sort of precursor to the TIE Bomber. It looks very gunshippy, and we know the Empire (in both canon and legends) loves to evolve their various lines of ships, building on what came before. They were probably looking for a more bomber/gunship oriented starfighter, said 'hey the TIE design's good, let's modify/evolve that', and this is their first attempt before getting to the full elongated twin pod model we see in ESB.

Comment: While valid points, do you have any evidence, from interviews either for this plane or other canonical sources that would suggest this kind of development?

Answer (score -2):

I'm thinking that perhaps its the [TIE Big gun](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE_Experimental_M2), I know that the TIE big gun looks different in legends but if you notice it has larger cannons on the small pod, so maybe?

Comment: This ship looks nothing like the TIE ExM2 "Big Gun".

Answer (score -2):

I think it is either a TIE attack craft, like a kid of the fighter and the TIE bomber, or a new version of the TIE bizzaro, but most likely it is a TIE with an upgraded sencer package to help other TIE's to navigate the maw.

Comment: This seems to be just speculation. Do you have any evidence to support these ideas?

Answer (score -2):

It's a TIE Seeker, they we're mostly deployed in the unknown regions to map new territories. However, seeing as their sensors were very advanced they can also function as pathfinders for other lesser TIE models to help navigate spacial hazards. In short, very expensive and rarely deployed except on critical missions.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We prefer our answers to be backed up by references to the source material. As far as I can tell, this is headcanon.